# How to implements touch listerner continuous like keyReapted (Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

I implements IOnSceneTouchListener and override method in class and i implements in scene

```
  scene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);

  scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);          

public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

Log.v("TouchEvent X",""+pSceneTouchEvent.getX());
Log.v("TouchEvent Y",""+pSceneTouchEvent.getY());

return true;
}
```

and i able to get x any y position for every touch. How i get x and y postion for continuous touch

Answer (score 0):

If by continuous you mean `dragging/sliding` over the screen, then you need to implement `GestureListener`. And measure initial `.getX()`, `getY()` and final `getX()`,`getY()`coordinates, since it allows you two `MotionEvents`.

Comment: I mean continuous finger pressed not dragging . If i dragging i get x any y postion when i make return true.

Comment: Then you need `onLongTouch` listener on that view.

Comment: Its problem in emulator. while run in device its working fine